# Need to deny DML access through SSMS using web app credentials

Tags: sql-server, security, configuration

A user can login to some web application and can submit any application which will affect the data(insert/update) in database, but that specific user should not be able to manipulate the data through SSMS login with the same credentials.

How can we configure this role?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of a role can't be defined by the application being used.

There are a couple of approaches that might work, but both will require code changes:

1. Enforce all data manipulation to go through stored procedures (you can grant execute to the app credentials and deny direct insert/update/delete). The app would call the stored procedures. To ensure users aren't calling the procedures directly in SSMS (or from their own VBScripts or other local code), the procedures could check `APP_NAME()` to decide whether or not to proceed.
2. If you can't enforce all data manipulation through stored procedures, then you could have `INSTEAD OF` triggers on all (or the most important) tables, which would perform a similar check against `APP_NAME()`, and then either perform the operation or not.

Keep in mind that the application name can be spoofed, so anything that relies on the output of `APP_NAME()` is vulnerable to tampering.

A more foolproof way would be to create separate logins altogether - better guard the credentials for the app, which you trust, from your developers, who you don't. (And as TomV mentions below, use Windows authentication for the app, so developers will have a much harder time pretending to act on its behalf.)

Comment: Since it's a web app I would also suggest to use windows authentication for the app by configuring the application pool using a service account. That way the dev's can't "reuse" the login they need for their application

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I heard that, we can configure this within SSMS only.

Comment: @Venkat Heard what, where? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry Aaron. You are correct. Actually I am searching for an option from user role configuration. But we don't have any option to configure as per my requirement. As you said, only the way is creating procedure. Thank you very much.